# I'm looking for a function $f(x,y,z)$, which has partial derivatives only in single point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Function must be defined in $\mathbb R$. I know that Dirichlet function is involved somehow, but i still can't find out an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usually, let $D(x)$ be the characteristic function of the set of all rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of the set of all  real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) for more info). The function $f(x,y,z):=(x^2+y^2+z^2)D(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ has the required property, being  differentiable only at the origin.